# How to get method count in a type (interface/class/enum) in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, count, methods, metrics

I want to know how many methods an interface declares or a class/enum implements. How to get that in Eclipse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A plugin like **[metrics](http://metrics.sourceforge.net/)** could give you that:

[image: Metrics View]

---

The [eclipse-metrics](http://eclipse-metrics.sourceforge.net/example/Type12.1.html) plugin (another one) provided also a similar metric (Weighted Methods per Class)

[image: Cyclomatic Calculator]

Comment: The site do not open... :(

Comment: @amit_yo which site does not open? Do you have an url?

Comment: http://metrics.sourceforge.net/ is not opening neither is http://eclipse-metrics.sourceforge.net/example/Type12.1.html.

Comment: @amit_yo Both are opening just fine on my side (France). Do you have some kind of proxy/firewall preventing you to access those sites?