# Easiest way to know LOC on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, metrics

I am working on a project using Eclipse 3.4.2, and would like to know how many Non Comment Lines of Code (NCLOC) it has.

It is OK to be a simple plugin, but I don't wan too much bloat. My machine is already slow the way it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a metric plugin (like the ones I mention in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831570/how-to-get-method-count-in-a-type-interface-class-enum-in-eclipse))

That, plus a good [eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590) (making your eclipse run with the latest JDK), should make your configuration able to display what you want in a timely fashion.

Comment: I think the plugins you mentioned will do the trick. Since a report is generated on demand, the is no reason they can impact Eclipse's performance.

Comment: The metric plug-in seems to be not compatible with recent versions of Eclipse.

Comment: @usr1234567 8 years later, that wouldn't be a surprise ;) Are you talking about http://metrics.sourceforge.net/ or http://eclipse-metrics.sourceforge.net/? The latter should be compatible (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-metrics)

Answer (score 5):

Use Eclipse regular Expression: Search->File, check Regular expression.

- LOC: \n[\s]* (without blanks)
- Comments: [*]+

you can subtract to get NCLOC with selected resource