# Eclipse count lines of code

Tags: eclipse, metrics, line-count

I've tried the [Metrics plugin](http://metrics.sourceforge.net) and although it's nice and all, it's not what my boss is looking for. It counts a line with just one `}` as a line and he doesn't want that to count as "its not a line, its a style choice". I also need to generate some form of report about the metrics provided. Are there any good tools for this?

Comment: Side question: is this to be used as a metric to show how well your software developers are working? If so character/non-whitespace count might be better. Even still it seems like a really arbitrary metric... As a friend stated: "in general more lines of code to solve a problem is not better (or worse) than less lines of code to solve the same problem"

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Install the [Eclipse Metrics Plugin](http://www.stateofflow.com/projects/16/eclipsemetrics). To create a HTML report (with optional XML and CSV) `right-click a project -> Export -> Other -> Metrics`.

You can adjust the Lines of Code metrics by ignoring blank and comment-only lines or exclude Javadoc if you want. To do this check the tab at `Preferences -> Metrics -> LoC`.

That's it. There is no special option to exclude curly braces `{}`.

The plugin offers an alternative metric to LoC called [Number of Statements](http://eclipse-metrics.sourceforge.net/descriptions/pages/NumberOfStatements.html). This is what the author has to say about it:

> *This metric represents the number of statements in a method. I consider it a more robust measure than Lines of Code since the latter is fragile with respect to different formatting conventions.*

Edit:

After you clarified your question, I understand that you need a view for real-time metrics violations, like compiler warnings or errors. You also need a reporting functionality to create reports for your boss. The plugin I described above is for reporting because you have to export the metrics when you want to see them.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for and nice export feature.

Comment: The current version of this plugin (3.14.1) doesn't appear to work with Eclipse Luna (4.4). Surprisingly, the ancient Metrics plugin from Sourceforge still works...

Comment: Many people report that it's not working any more, but nobody files a bug at SourceForge...

Comment: Yeah. I am not able to see any options under `right click a project -> Export`, I have installed plug-in directly from eclipse marketplace - version is - `Eclipse Metrics 3.12.0`, can anyone please help me. thanks!

Comment: There is a working version - https://github.com/qxo/eclipse-metrics-plugin/blob/master/updatesite/plugins/net.sourceforge.metrics_1.3.10.jar

Answer (score 288):

There's always the "brute force":

1. Search->File
2. Type the following in "Containing text" -> `^.*$`. Then check the "Regular Expression" checkbox
3. Type the following in "File name patterns" -> `*.java`
4. Click "Search"
5. Check the number of matches in the "Search" Tab.

Comment: This did exactly what I was looking for.  It doesn't exclude brackets or anything fancy, but it gives the answer I was looking for, IN eclipse, WITHOUT plugins.  Thanks!

Comment: counts everything including comments, would be nice if it counts lines of actual statements

Comment: In eclipse you can define working sets if you would like to get this number separately for src, test, or by any folder. Thanks for the trick!

Comment: You can also use `\n[\s]*` and it will ignore empty lines as well

Comment: This works with latest (neon) eclipse but metrics plugin does not

Comment: Is there any chance to exclude comments?

Comment: @omerio comments have to be typed as well and are necessary part of any source code. Not counting those induces they wouldn't be important or are just blind text - which is a serious mistake.

Comment: `^.*\w.*$` includes only lines with at least one ascii alphanumeric character. Use this for excluding empty lines, bracket-only lines etc.

Comment: And it even works for C if you change *.java to *.c, *.h   ;-)

Comment: Seems a bit silly, as it doesn't count comments or so, but hey, it can giver a rough view without need of plugins, so thats a smart solution after all

Comment: nice clue, suggesting this improved regex: "^\s*(}\s+)?[a-zA-Z0-9{+_@"-].+$" that would not count lone closing brackets, neither empty nor pure comment lines

Answer (score 23):

If on OSX or *NIX use

Get all actual lines of java code from *.java files

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec grep "[a-zA-Z0-9{}]" {} \; | wc -l
```

Get all lines from the *.java files, which includes empty lines and comments

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec cat | wc -l
```

Get information per File, this will give you [ path to file + "," + number of lines ]

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec wc -l {} \;
```

Comment: Running the first command on OSX I get: grep: invalid character range
       0

Comment: This has worked for me find . -name "*.java" | xargs cat | grep  '[alnum]' | wc -l

Comment: should be `find . -name "*.java" | xargs cat | grep "[a-zA-Z0-9{}]" | wc -l`

Answer (score 13):

One possible way to count lines of code in Eclipse:

using the Search / File... menu, select File Search tab, specify \n[\s]* for Containing text (this will not count empty lines), and tick Regular expression.

Hat tip: [www.monblocnotes.com/node/2030](http://www.monblocnotes.com/node/2030)

Comment: wow, that's super genius.  nice to have it not count blank lines, as long as you're not paid by the number...

Comment: Also select "*.java" (or your extension) to focus on the code files

Answer (score 8):

Another way would by to use another loc utility, like [LocMetrics](http://www.locmetrics.com/index.html) for instance.
It also lists many [other loc tools](http://www.locmetrics.com/alternatives.html).
The integration with Eclipse wouldn't be always there (as it would be with **[Metrics2](http://metrics2.sourceforge.net/)**, which you can check out because it is a more recent version than [Metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831570/how-to-get-method-count-in-a-type-interface-class-enum-in-eclipse)), but at least those tools can reason in term of **logical lines** (computed by summing the terminal semicolons and terminal curly braces).
You can also check with [eclipse-metrics](http://eclipse-metrics.sourceforge.net/) is more adapted to what you expect.

Answer (score 7):

Another tool is [Google Analytix](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-codepro), which will also allow you to run metrics even if you can`t build the project in case of errors

Comment: Although the site says it's only for older versions of eclipse, it works just fine on Luna for me.  Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Eclipse plugin, which can count the lines of source code.
It support Kotlin, Java, Java Script, JSP, XML, C/C++, C#, and many other file types.

Please take a look at it.
Any feedback would be appreciated!

[the git-hub repository is here](https://github.com/LiYing2010/SourceCounter)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to determine your definition of "line of code" (LOC).  In both your question

> It counts a line with just one } as a line and he doesn't want that to
>   count as "its not a line, its a style choice"

and in the answers, e.g.,

> You can adjust the Lines of Code metrics by ignoring blank and comment-only lines or exclude Javadoc if you want

you can tell that people have different opinions as to what constitutes a line of code.  In particular, people are often imprecise about whether they really want the number of lines of code or the number of statements.  For example, if you have the following really long line filled with statements, what do you want to report, 1 LOC or hundreds of statements?

```
{ a = 1; b = 2; if (a==c) b++; /* etc. for another 1000 characters */ }
```

And when somebody asks you what you are calling a LOC, make sure you can answer, even if it is just "my definition of a LOC is Metrics2's definition".  In general, for most commonly formatted code (unlike my example), the popular tools will give numbers fairly similar, so Metrics2, SonarQube, etc. should all be fine, as long as you use them consistently.  In other words, don't count the LOC of some code using one tool and compare that value to a later version of that code that was measured with a different tool.

Answer (score 0):

ProjectCodeMeter counts LLOC (logical lines of code) exactly as you described (only effective lines). it integrates into [eclipse as external code metrics tool](http://www.projectcodemeter.com/cost_estimation/help/FN_commandline.htm), it's not real-time though, it generates a report.actually it counts many source code metrics such as complexity, arithmetic intricacy, hard coded strings, numeric constants.. even estimates development time in hours.

Answer (score 0):

For static analysis, I've used and recommend SonarQube which runs [just about all the metrics you could possibly want](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Metric+definitions) on [a wide range of languages](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+Library), and is free in the basic version (you have to pay to analyse the sorts of languages I'd only code in with a gun to my head).

You have to install it as a web-app running the analysis off your source code repository, but it also has an [Eclipse plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse).

It's overkill if you just want to know, as a one-off, how many lines of code there are in your project. If you want to track metrics through time, compare across projects, fire warnings when a threshold is exceeded, etc., it's fantastic.

Disclosure: I have no financial relationship with SonarSource.