# Lines of code you have written

Tags: perforce, lines-of-code

Out of curiosity, is there any way to get the number of lines of code you have written (in a specific project)?

I tried perforce with `p4 describe #CLN | wc -l`, but apart from so many edge cases (comments being included, new lines being added etc.), it skips the newly added files as well. Edge cases can be ignored, if we try to display physical line of code but newly added files still cause the issue.

Comment: I tried p4 describe #CLN | wc -l but I got error Usage: describe [-d<flags> -a -m max -s -S -f -O -I] changelist# ...
Missing/wrong number of arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers seem to have missed the source-control history side of things.

From http://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/359-how-many-lines-of-code-have-i-written/

Calculate the answer in multiple steps:

1) Added files:

```
p4 filelog ... | grep ' add on .* by <username>'
p4 print -q foo#1 | wc -l
```

2) Changed files:

```
p4 describe <changelist> | grep "^>" | wc -l
```

Combine all the counts together (scripting...), and you'll have a total.

You might also want to get rid of whitespace lines, or lines without alphanumeric chars, with a grep?

Also if you are doing it regularly, it would be more efficient to code the thing in P4Python and do it incrementally - keeping history and looking at only new commits.

Comment: Thanks but first doesn't see to show all the files (only the ones submitted from current workspace). 
And are the results pushed to foo#1? Do I need to run for every single file?

Comment: You'll have to do the rest of the scripting to take the file names from the first command, and run the second command on each one.

Comment: Actually looking at the output, more processing might be required, anyway.

Comment: `p4 filelog -s -L ... | grep ' add on .* by DouglasLeeder\|^//' | grep -B1 "add on" | grep "^//"` gives me all the paths that I've added, in the directory I run the command.

Answer (score 5):

I went ahead and wrote a Python script that prints out the number of lines of code added/changed by a user and the average number of lines per change.

Tested on Windows with Python 2.7.2. You can run from the command line - it assumes you have p4 in your path.

Usage: codestats.py -u [username]

It works with git too: codestats.py -u [authorname] -g.

It does some blacklisting to prune out bulk adds (e.g. you just added a library), and also imposes a blacklist on certain types of files (e.g. .HTML files, etc.). Otherwise, it works pretty well.

Hope this helps!

```
########################################################################
# Script that computes the lines of code stats for a perforce/git user.
########################################################################

import argparse
import logging
import subprocess
import sys
import re

VALID_ARGUMENTS = [
    ("user", "-u", "--user", "Run lines of code computation for the specified user.", 1),
    ("change", "-c", "--change", "Just display lines of code in the passed in change (useful for debugging).", 1),
    ("git", "-g", "--git", "Use git rather than perforce (which is the default versioning system queried).", 0)
]

class PrintHelpOnErrorArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
  def error(self, message):
    logging.error("error: {0}\n\n".format(message))
    self.print_help()
    sys.exit(2)

def is_code_file(depot_path):
  fstat_output = subprocess.Popen(['p4', 'fstat', depot_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split('\n')
  text_file = False
  head_type_regex = re.compile('^... headType (\S+)\s*$')
  for line in fstat_output:
    head_type_line = head_type_regex.match(line)
    if head_type_line:
      head_type = head_type_line.group(1)

      text_file = (head_type.find('text') != -1)

  if text_file:
    blacklisted_file_types = ['html', 'css', 'twb', 'twbx', 'tbm', 'xml']

    for file_type in blacklisted_file_types:
      if re.match('^\/\/depot.*\.{}#\d+$'.format(file_type), depot_path):
        text_file = False
        break

  return text_file

def parse_args():
  parser = PrintHelpOnErrorArgumentParser()

  for arg_name, short_switch, long_switch, help, num_args in VALID_ARGUMENTS:
    if num_args != 0:
        parser.add_argument(
            short_switch,
            nargs=num_args,
            type=str,
            dest=arg_name)
    else:
        parser.add_argument(
            long_switch,
            short_switch,
            action="store_true",
            help=help,
            dest=arg_name)

  return parser.parse_args()

file_edited_regex = re.compile('^... .*?#\d+ edit\s*$')
file_deleted_regex = re.compile('^... .*?#\d+ delete\s*$')
file_integrated_regex = re.compile('^... .*?#\d+ integrate\s*$')
file_added_regex = re.compile('^... (.*?#\d+) add\s*$')
affected_files_regex = re.compile('^Affected files ...')
outliers = [] # Changes that seem as if they weren't hand coded and merit inspection

def num_lines_in_file(depot_path):
  lines = len(subprocess.Popen(['p4', 'print', depot_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split('\n'))
  return lines

def parse_change(changelist):
  change_description = subprocess.Popen(['p4', 'describe', '-ds', changelist], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split('\n')

  parsing_differences = False
  parsing_affected_files = False

  differences_regex = re.compile('^Differences \.\.\..*$')
  line_added_regex = re.compile('^add \d+ chunks (\d+) lines.*$')
  line_removed_regex = re.compile('^deleted \d+ chunks (\d+) lines.*$')
  line_changed_regex = re.compile('^changed \d+ chunks (\d+) / (\d+) lines.*$')
  file_diff_regex = re.compile('^==== (\/\/depot.*#\d+)\s*\S+$')
  skip_file = False

  num_lines_added = 0
  num_lines_deleted = 0
  num_lines_changed_added = 0
  num_lines_changed_deleted = 0
  num_files_added = 0
  num_files_edited = 0

  for line in change_description:
    if differences_regex.match(line):
      parsing_differences = True
    elif affected_files_regex.match(line):
      parsing_affected_files = True
    elif parsing_differences:
      if file_diff_regex.match(line):
        regex_match = file_diff_regex.match(line)
        skip_file = not is_code_file(regex_match.group(1))
      elif not skip_file:
        regex_match = line_added_regex.match(line)
        if regex_match:
          num_lines_added += int(regex_match.group(1))
        else:
          regex_match = line_removed_regex.match(line)

          if regex_match:
            num_lines_deleted += int(regex_match.group(1))
          else:
            regex_match = line_changed_regex.match(line)

            if regex_match:
              num_lines_changed_added += int(regex_match.group(2))
              num_lines_changed_deleted += int(regex_match.group(1))

    elif parsing_affected_files:
      if file_added_regex.match(line):
        file_added_match = file_added_regex.match(line)
        depot_path = file_added_match.group(1)

        if is_code_file(depot_path):
          lines_in_file = num_lines_in_file(depot_path)

          if lines_in_file > 3000:
            # Anomaly - probably a copy of existing code - discard this
            lines_in_file = 0

          num_lines_added += lines_in_file

        num_files_added += 1
      elif file_edited_regex.match(line):
        num_files_edited += 1

  return [num_files_added, num_files_edited, num_lines_added, num_lines_deleted, num_lines_changed_added, num_lines_changed_deleted]

def contains_integrates(changelist):
  change_description = subprocess.Popen(['p4', 'describe', '-s', changelist], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split('\n')

  contains_integrates = False
  parsing_affected_files = False

  for line in change_description:
    if affected_files_regex.match(line):
      parsing_affected_files = True
    elif parsing_affected_files:
      if file_integrated_regex.match(line):
        contains_integrates = True
        break

  return contains_integrates

#################################################
# Note: Keep this function in sync with 
# generate_line.
#################################################
def generate_output_specifier(output_headers):
  output_specifier = ''

  for output_header in output_headers:
    output_specifier += '| {:'
    output_specifier += '{}'.format(len(output_header))
    output_specifier += '}'

  if output_specifier != '':
    output_specifier += ' |'

  return output_specifier

#################################################
# Note: Keep this function in sync with 
# generate_output_specifier.
#################################################
def generate_line(output_headers):
  line = ''

  for output_header in output_headers:
    line += '--' # for the '| '
    header_padding_specifier = '{:-<'
    header_padding_specifier += '{}'.format(len(output_header))
    header_padding_specifier += '}'
    line += header_padding_specifier.format('')

  if line != '':
    line += '--' # for the last ' |'

  return line

# Returns true if a change is a bulk addition or a private change
def is_black_listed_change(user, changelist):
  large_add_change = False
  all_adds = True
  num_adds = 0
  is_private_change = False
  is_third_party_change = False

  change_description = subprocess.Popen(['p4', 'describe', '-s', changelist], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split('\n')

  for line in change_description:
    if file_edited_regex.match(line) or file_deleted_regex.match(line):
      all_adds = False
    elif file_added_regex.match(line):
      num_adds += 1

    if line.find('... //depot/private') != -1:
      is_private_change = True
      break

    if line.find('... //depot/third-party') != -1:
      is_third_party_change = True
      break

  large_add_change = all_adds and num_adds > 70

  #print "{}: {}".format(changelist, large_add_change or is_private_change)
  return large_add_change or is_third_party_change

change_header_regex = re.compile('^Change (\d+)\s*.*?\s*(\S+)@.*$')

def get_user_and_change_header_for_change(changelist):
  change_description = subprocess.Popen(['p4', 'describe', '-s', changelist], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split('\n')

  user = None
  change_header = None

  for line in change_description:
    change_header_match = change_header_regex.match(line)

    if change_header_match:
      user = change_header_match.group(2)
      change_header = line
      break

  return [user, change_header]

if __name__ == "__main__":
  log = logging.getLogger()
  log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

  args = parse_args()
  user_stats = {}
  user_stats['num_changes'] = 0
  user_stats['lines_added'] = 0
  user_stats['lines_deleted'] = 0
  user_stats['lines_changed_added'] = 0
  user_stats['lines_changed_removed'] = 0
  user_stats['total_lines'] = 0
  user_stats['files_edited'] = 0
  user_stats['files_added'] = 0

  change_log = []

  if args.git:
    git_log_command = ['git', 'log', '--author={}'.format(args.user[0]), '--pretty=tformat:', '--numstat']
    git_log_output = subprocess.Popen(git_log_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split('\n')

    git_log_line_regex = re.compile('^(\d+)\s*(\d+)\s*\S+$')
    total = 0
    adds = 0
    subs = 0
    for git_log_line in git_log_output:
      line_match = git_log_line_regex.match(git_log_line)

      if line_match:
        adds += int(line_match.group(1))
        subs += int(line_match.group(2))

    total = adds - subs
    num_commits = 0

    git_shortlog_command = ['git', 'shortlog', '--author={}'.format(args.user[0]), '-s']
    git_shortlog_output = subprocess.Popen(git_shortlog_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split('\n')

    git_shortlog_line_regex = re.compile('^\s*(\d+)\s+.*$')
    for git_shortlog_line in git_shortlog_output:
      line_match = git_shortlog_line_regex.match(git_shortlog_line)
      if line_match:
        num_commits += int(line_match.group(1))

    print "Git Stats for {}: Commits: {}. Lines of code: {}. Average Lines Per Change: {}.".format(args.user[0], num_commits, total, total*1.0/num_commits)
    sys.exit(0)
  elif args.change:
    [args.user, change_header] = get_user_and_change_header_for_change(args.change)
    change_log = [change_header]
  else:
    change_log = subprocess.Popen(['p4', 'changes', '-u', args.user, '-s', 'submitted'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split('\n')

  output_headers = ['Current Change', 'Num Changes', 'Files Added', 'Files Edited']
  output_headers.append('Lines Added')
  output_headers.append('Lines Deleted')

  if not args.git:
    output_headers.append('Lines Changed (Added/Removed)')

  avg_change_size = 0.0
  output_headers.append('Total Lines')
  output_headers.append('Avg. Lines/Change')

  line = generate_line(output_headers)
  output_specifier = generate_output_specifier(output_headers)

  print line

  print output_specifier.format(*output_headers)
  print line

  output_specifier_with_carriage_return = output_specifier + '\r'

  for change in change_log:
    change_match = change_header_regex.search(change)

    if change_match:
      user_stats['num_changes'] += 1

      changelist = change_match.group(1)

      if not is_black_listed_change(args.user, changelist) and not contains_integrates(changelist):
        [files_added_in_change, files_edited_in_change, lines_added_in_change, lines_deleted_in_change, lines_changed_added_in_change, lines_changed_removed_in_change] = parse_change(change_match.group(1))
        if lines_added_in_change > 5000 and changelist not in outliers:
          outliers.append([changelist, lines_added_in_change])
        else:
          user_stats['lines_added'] += lines_added_in_change
          user_stats['lines_deleted'] += lines_deleted_in_change
          user_stats['lines_changed_added'] += lines_changed_added_in_change
          user_stats['lines_changed_removed'] += lines_changed_removed_in_change
          user_stats['total_lines'] += lines_changed_added_in_change
          user_stats['total_lines'] -= lines_changed_removed_in_change
          user_stats['total_lines'] += lines_added_in_change
          user_stats['files_edited'] += files_edited_in_change
          user_stats['files_added'] += files_added_in_change

      current_output = [changelist, user_stats['num_changes'], user_stats['files_added'], user_stats['files_edited']]

      current_output.append(user_stats['lines_added'])
      current_output.append(user_stats['lines_deleted'])

      if not args.git:
        current_output.append('{}/{}'.format(user_stats['lines_changed_added'], user_stats['lines_changed_removed']))

      current_output.append(user_stats['total_lines'])
      current_output.append(user_stats['total_lines']*1.0/user_stats['num_changes'])

      print output_specifier_with_carriage_return.format(*current_output),

  print
  print line

  if len(outliers) > 0:
    print "Outliers (changes that merit inspection - and have not been included in the stats):"
    outlier_headers = ['Changelist', 'Lines of Code']
    outlier_specifier = generate_output_specifier(outlier_headers)
    outlier_line = generate_line(outlier_headers)

    print outlier_line
    print outlier_specifier.format(*outlier_headers)
    print outlier_line

    for change in outliers:
      print outlier_specifier.format(*change)

    print outlier_line
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are many ways to count lines of code.

**tl;dr** Install [Eclipse Metrics Plugin](http://www.stateofflow.com/projects/16/eclipsemetrics). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924158/eclipse-count-lines-of-code) is the instruction how to do it. Below there is a short script if you want to do it without Eclipse.

**Shell script**

I will present you quite general approach. It works on Linux, however it's portable to other systems. Save this 2 lines to `lines.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
find -name "*.java" | awk '{ system("wc "$0)  }' | awk '{ print $1 "\t" $4; lines += $1; files++ } END { print "Total: " lines " lines in " files " files."}'
```

It's a shell script which uses `find`, `wc` and great [`awk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK). Add permission to execute:

`chmod +x lines.sh`

Now we can execute our shell script.

Let's say you saved `lines.sh` in `/home/you/workspace/projectX`.
Script counts lines in `.java` files, which are located in subdirectories of `/home/you/workspace/projectX`.

So let's run it with `./lines.sh`. You can change `*.java` for any other types of files.

Sample output:

```
adam@adam ~/workspace/Checkers $ ./lines.sh 
23  ./src/Checkers.java
14  ./src/event/StartGameEvent.java
38  ./src/event/YourColorEvent.java
52  ./src/event/BoardClickEvent.java
61  ./src/event/GameQueue.java
14  ./src/event/PlayerEscapeEvent.java
14  ./src/event/WaitEvent.java
16  ./src/event/GameEvent.java
38  ./src/event/EndGameEvent.java
38  ./src/event/FakeBoardEvent.java
127 ./src/controller/ServerThread.java
14  ./src/controller/ServerConfig.java
46  ./src/controller/Server.java
170 ./src/controller/Controller.java
141 ./src/controller/ServerNetwork.java
246 ./src/view/ClientNetwork.java
36  ./src/view/Messages.java
53  ./src/view/ButtonField.java
47  ./src/view/ViewConfig.java
32  ./src/view/MainWindow.java
455 ./src/view/View.java
36  ./src/view/ImageLoader.java
88  ./src/model/KingJump.java
130 ./src/model/Cords.java
70  ./src/model/King.java
77  ./src/model/FakeBoard.java
90  ./src/model/CheckerMove.java
53  ./src/model/PlayerColor.java
73  ./src/model/Checker.java
201 ./src/model/AbstractPiece.java
75  ./src/model/CheckerJump.java
154 ./src/model/Model.java
105 ./src/model/KingMove.java
99  ./src/model/FieldType.java
269 ./src/model/Board.java
56  ./src/model/AbstractJump.java
80  ./src/model/AbstractMove.java
82  ./src/model/BoardState.java
Total: 3413 lines in 38 files.
```

Answer (score 0):

Find an app to calculate the lines, there are many subtleties to counting lines - comments, blank lines, multiple operators per line etc.

Visual Studio has "Calculate Code Metrics" functionality, since you're not mentioning one single language I can't be more specific about which tool to use, just saying "find" and "grep" may not be the way to go.

Also consider the fact that lines of code don't measure actual progress. Completed features on your roadmap measures progress and the lower the lines of code - the better. It wouldn't be a first if a proud developer claims his 60,000 lines of code are marvelous only to find out there's a way to do the same thing in 1000 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SLOCCount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/). It only counts actual lines of code and performs some additional computations as well.

On OSX, you can easily install it via Homebrew with `brew install sloccount`.

Sample output for a project of mine:

```
$ sloccount .
Have a non-directory at the top, so creating directory top_dir
Adding /Users/padde/Desktop/project/./Gemfile to top_dir
Adding /Users/padde/Desktop/project/./Gemfile.lock to top_dir
Adding /Users/padde/Desktop/project/./Procfile to top_dir
Adding /Users/padde/Desktop/project/./README to top_dir
Adding /Users/padde/Desktop/project/./application.rb to top_dir
Creating filelist for config
Adding /Users/padde/Desktop/project/./config.ru to top_dir
Creating filelist for controllers
Creating filelist for db
Creating filelist for helpers
Creating filelist for models
Creating filelist for public
Creating filelist for tmp
Creating filelist for views
Categorizing files.
Finding a working MD5 command....
Found a working MD5 command.
Computing results.


SLOC    Directory   SLOC-by-Language (Sorted)
256     controllers     ruby=256
66      models          ruby=66
10      config          ruby=10
9       top_dir         ruby=9
5       helpers         ruby=5
0       db              (none)
0       public          (none)
0       tmp             (none)
0       views           (none)


Totals grouped by language (dominant language first):
ruby:           346 (100.00%)




Total Physical Source Lines of Code (SLOC)                = 346
Development Effort Estimate, Person-Years (Person-Months) = 0.07 (0.79)
 (Basic COCOMO model, Person-Months = 2.4 * (KSLOC**1.05))
Schedule Estimate, Years (Months)                         = 0.19 (2.28)
 (Basic COCOMO model, Months = 2.5 * (person-months**0.38))
Estimated Average Number of Developers (Effort/Schedule)  = 0.34
Total Estimated Cost to Develop                           = $ 8,865
 (average salary = $56,286/year, overhead = 2.40).
SLOCCount, Copyright (C) 2001-2004 David A. Wheeler
SLOCCount is Open Source Software/Free Software, licensed under the GNU GPL.
SLOCCount comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, and you are welcome to
redistribute it under certain conditions as specified by the GNU GPL license;
see the documentation for details.
Please credit this data as "generated using David A. Wheeler's 'SLOCCount'."
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an easier way to do all this, which incidentally is faster than using grep:

First get all the change lists for a particular user, this is a commandline command you can use it in python script by using os.system():

```
p4 changes -u <username> > 'some_text_file.txt'
```

Now you need to extract all the changelists number so ,we will use regex for it, here it is done using python :

```
f = open('some_text_file.txt','r')
lists = f.readlines()
pattern = re.compile(r'\b[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\b')

labels = []
for i in lists:
    labels.append(pattern.findall(i))

changelists = []
for h in labels:
    if(type(h) is list):
        changelists.append(str(h[0]))
    else:
        changelists.append(str(h))
```

Now that you have all the changelists numbers in 'labels'.
We will iterate through the list and for every changelist find number of lines added and number of lines deleted, getting the ultimate difference would give us total number of lines added. The following liens of code do exactly that:

```
for i in changelists:
    os.system('p4 describe -ds '+i+' | findstr "^add" >> added.txt')
    os.system('p4 describe -ds '+i+' | findstr "^del" >> deleted.txt')

added = []
deleted = []

file = open('added.txt')
for i in file:
    added.append(i)

count = []
count_added = 0
count_add = 0
count_del = 0

for j in added:
    count = [int(s) for s in j.split() if s.isdigit()]
    count_add += count[1]
    count = []


file = open('deleted.txt')
for i in file:
    deleted.append(i)

for j in labels:
    count = [int(s) for s in j.split() if s.isdigit()]
    count_del += count[1]
    count = []

count_added = count_add - count_del

print count_added
```

count_added will have number of lines that were added by the user.