# How to calculate number of lines of code which every programmer added or removed in perforce version control

Tags: shell, version-control, perforce, p4v, lines-of-code

I want get statistic about how many every developer added and removed lines of code in perforce version control system in all changelist in all time. The result must be like:

| user | added | removed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| evgeny | 32152 | 50021 |
| pavel | 14298 | 1598 |

Comment: I tried to understand how it do, but it does not helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201754/lines-of-code-you-have-written

Comment: You could script this pretty easily using `p4 annotate -a`.